# Streambuilder and AnimatedContainer

Tags: flutter

#### Project

Hi, I'm trying to use this layout in flutter

[image]

I want the top container to be set with an initial size and then let his dimension be controlled by a stream

#### Code

```
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: streamController.stream ,
        initialData: initialData ,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
          return AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            height: 200,
          );
        },
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Problem is that this will never work in flutter, because I have to provide an height to column's children and in this case stream builder doesn't have one.
I've already tried as soomeone suggested in other post to wrap stream builder in a flexible widget and use `Flexfit.loose` but that was not the solution for me and leaded to this result:

[image]

Is there a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working as you want, isn't it?

[image: demo]

```dart
final streamController = StreamController<double>.broadcast();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream: streamController.stream,
                  initialData: 200.0,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return AnimatedContainer(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                      height: snapshot.data,
                      color: Colors.blue
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        streamController.add(Random().nextDouble() * 200);
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding where i was wrong. I think you are referring to the fact that inside streambuilder i used a fixed height instead of using snapshot.data. This was a mistake I've done tryng to simplify the code to post here. The compiler was complaining because it didn' found a proper size for streambuilder. In any case, your code works as I intended so thanks a lot, appreciated